# Big Commerce Stock Level on Category Pages

Tags: bigcommerce

I've been stuck on this issue for a while and I've had no luck getting any good information from the message boards at Big Commerce. Does anyone know how to retrieve stock level information for products on category pages (not individual product-detail pages)? I want to be able to display the stock amount on the category page, but the variable I'm using does not work (%%GLOBAL_InventoryList%%). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the %%GLOBAL_InventoryList%% variable to the Snippets/CategoryProductsItem.html template does the trick.